# Python: Read specific element from a matrix written in a file with string

Tags: python, readlines

I would like to read data from a matrix in a file, the problem is the data is float with string, however, I am interested only in reading the float element,
I tried with several options including pandas dataframe, however, I could not so I am kindly asking for help.

I am attaching the file as picture as I could not upload the file itself, and the code:

```
with open('data.dat', 'r') as f:
output_data = f.readlines()
element =  [(d+' ')[:d.find(':')].rstrip() for d in output_data] # trying to read only number after ":" 
print(output_data[0]) 
 # EXPECTED OUTPUT is: 
  0.162239678E+01
 # CURRENT OUTPUT IS: ['  data  1:           0.162239678E+01\n', '  data  2:           0.413951524E+01']



## data.dat    is as the following:
  data  1:           0.162239678E+01
  data  2:           0.413951524E+01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have the correct approach, but somehow you're targeting the first part of each line instead of the actual number. The problem is this: `[:d.find(':')]`, you want the other side of the string: `[d.find(':'):]`. Also, you'll be capturing the `":"` character, so add 1 to the position. Then, use `str.strip` instead of `str.rstrip` to apply the function on both sides of the string. This is the resulting code (with some simplifications):

```
with open('data.dat', 'r') as f:
    output_data = f.readlines()
    elements =  [d[d.find(':')+1:].strip() for d in output_data]
    print(elements)
```